# Time Machine issue: How do I restore email originally backed using Mojave to Catalina?

Tags: backup, time-machine, imac, ssd, kernel-panic

Last month, the hard drive on my 2013 iMac died. Luckily I have a full backup on Time Machine (backed up with Mojave 10.14.6 (18G103)).

However, I have a problem now. I took my iMac to a certified Apple shop (not Genius Bar) and they installed a new SATA SSD drive with 16GB of RAM.  They also installed the latest macOS Catalina 10.15 (19A603). The problem is I cannot use Time Machine to restore my previously backed up Mojave environment, as I am getting the kernel panic error below:

[image: Kernel panic error when restoring from Time Machine]

I suspect the issue is that I am trying to restore a 32-bit operating system (Mojave) onto a 64-bit (Catalina).

So what I decided to do was to do a fresh/clean install of Catalina on my iMac, and simply copy my personal files over. That worked, but how do I import my old emails from Time Machine? This my true problem. I have over 8000 emails backed up on Time Machine (again under Mojave). How can I retrieve/import these emails and their local email structures (local storage) from Time Machine into my Catalina environment?